# Why the following function converges?

Tags: real-analysis

In the following link:

[Examples of dense sets in the complex plane](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/996246/examples-of-dense-sets-in-the-complex-plane)

we can see an example which  says that the following function converges:

$$f(x)=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{2^n}\frac{1}{x-r_n}\sin\left(\frac{1}{x-r_n}\right) $$

where $r_n$ is any fixed enumeration of the rational, and $f(r_n)=0$.

Why this expression converges?