# Open set in $\mathbb{C}$ with non-trivial boundary

Tags: general-topology, geometric-topology

When studying complex analysis - or even real analysis for that matter - we most times consider open sets $\Omega \subset \mathbb{C}$ (or $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2$) having smooth curves as its boundaries (Ex.: an open disk), or at least smooth by parts (Ex.: a triangle).

I assume that is necessary so we can deal with line integrals, Cauchy Formulas and that kind of thing. But from a purely topological curiosity, what are the possibilities for the boundary of an arbitrary open set? How complicated can it get? Can we give non-trivial examples explicitly?

Thanks!

Comment: I might be mistaken, but I think every nowhere dense closed set is the boundary of some open set...

Comment: so Cantor's set is the boundary of some open set $\Omega$? Can you exhibit $\Omega$?

Comment: That one's easy, it's the open intervals that you deleted from $[0,1]$ to construct it.

Comment: Cantor's set $S \subset \mathbb{R} \subset \mathbb{C}$ is the boundary of $\Omega = \mathbb{C}-S$.

Answer (score 2):

We can completely characterize the subsets of $\mathbb R^n$ that are the boundaries of open sets -- they are the closed, nowhere dense sets!

A set is *nowhere dense* if it has empty interior. These include

- Graphs of (continuous!) functions
- Level sets of polynomials
- Certain fractals, like the Cantor set
- Loops that don't intersect themselves.

**Proof**:
Suppose that the set $C=\partial U\subseteq\mathbb R^n$ is the boundary of the open subset $U\subseteq\mathbb R^n$. $C$ is automatically closed (this is true of *every* boundary). Because $U$ is open, $U\cap C=\varnothing$. Hence $C$ has empty interior.

Conversely, start with a closed, nowhere dense set $C$. Let $U$ denote the complement of $C$, so that $U$ is open. Then $C$ contains $\partial U$ because $\partial U\cap U = \varnothing$. Since $C$ also has empty interior, $C$ *is* the boundary of $U$ (why?). **QED**

In conclusion, **the boundaries of open sets are the closed, nowhere dense sets**. This should hold in any metric space and might even hold in greater generality, but I haven't thought about it.

To get back to your question about how nontrivial the boundaries of an open set can be, the answer is *very*. There are lots of closed, nowhere dense sets and most of them have no smoothness properties.

(This is an expansion of Ian's comment.)

Comment: *Graphs of functions* needs to be restricted a bit. There are functions from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$ whose graphs are dense in ${\mathbb R}^{2},$ such as [non-linear additive functions](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/131197/graph-of-discontinuous-linear-function-is-dense) (equivalently, discontinuous additive functions) and even certain [Baire 2 functions](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/996246/examples-of-dense-sets-in-the-complex-plane).

Comment: Your proof makes no specific reference to the type of topology and is applicable to all spaces.

Comment: There are some unusual situations that occur in C, such as 3 pair-wise disjoint open sets sharing the same boundary.