# Example of a dense set which is not nowhere dense

Tags: general-topology

I can't find an example of a dense set A in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ which is not nowhere dense. The definition of *nowhere dense* set given in the exercise is as follows:

> Let $\mathrm{X}$ be a topological space. A subset $\mathrm{A}$ $\subset$ $\mathrm{X}$ is **nowhere dense** in $\mathrm{X}$ if $\mathrm{X}$$\setminus$$\mathrm{A}$ is dense in $\mathrm{X}$.

I thought of something like $\mathbb{Q} \times (\pi\mathbb{Q})$ as I saw in this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/996246/examples-of-dense-sets-in-the-complex-plane), but I'm not sure that the complementary set is not dense in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$. Thank you for helping me.

Comment: How about $A=\mathbb R^2$? It is dense but its complement $\varnothing$ is not.

Comment: Yes you're right! I was thinking only of proper subset but this is not necessary. Thank you, it was easier that I thought!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition in your text defines a co-dense subset  (the complement is dense), don't confuse it with the bona fide usual concept of [a nowhere dense subset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nowhere_dense_set).

Take a closed set with empty interior and take its complement to get a lot of examples, e.g. in $\Bbb R^2$:

- $\Bbb R^2$ itself (trivial)
- $\{(x,y): y \neq 0\}$
- $\{(x,y): \|x\|\neq 1\}$

and many more.