# What is a Linear Transformation?

Tags: definition, linear-algebra

[Linear Transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map) is a term used often in physics. For example, we are told [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/32011/) that a tensor is a generalization of a linear transformation. I've never actually learned what they are, though. Could someone explain?

Comment: Do you know what a vector space is?

Comment: Yes, I do. Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A linear transformation $A:V\to W$ is a map between vector spaces $V$ and $W$ such that for any two vectors $v_1, v_2 \in V$,

$$A(v_1+v_2) = A(v_1) + A(v_2),$$

and for any scalar $\lambda$,

$$ A(\lambda v_1) = \lambda A(v_1).$$

In other words a linear transformation is a map between vector spaces that respects the linear structure of both vector spaces.

Comment: I think the second equation follows from the first

Comment: @user45664 it follows only for integral values of $\lambda$, not all $\lambda$

Comment: @user45664: *I think the second equation follows from the first* --- Assuming that we're dealing with scalars that are real numbers, then the second equation **for rational numbers** $\lambda$ follows from the first equation, but not for all real numbers. In particular, can you prove $A\left(\sqrt{2}v_1\right) = \sqrt{2}A(v_1)$ using only the first equation?

Comment: Regarding my previous comment, see [Cauchy's functional equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation). Functions that satisfy the first equation but not the second equation are extremely pathological. See [Graph of discontinuous additive function is dense in $\mathbb R^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/131197/13130) and [Overview of basic facts about Cauchy functional equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/423492/13130). FYI, having a dense graph [can actually be achieved by much less pathological functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/996872/13130).